# angularjs efficiency declaring controller inside or outside

Tags: angularjs

Having a bit of a more complicated issue, but one factor that I really want to know is this..

Does declaring a controller inside (second method) a partial which is not instantiated (yet) increase the efficiency of the app compared to declaring the controller in my index file (first method)

I would think it would be more efficient by having the ng-controller's inside the partials as if they would be outside, they would all have to be instantiated at once at the start as well as keeping more memory in usage at all times.

in terms of memory allocation, I tested both methods and both seem to give me about the same amount of memory used.

First method:

```
in "index.html:"

<div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">

   <div ng-switch="mainCtrl.currentPage">
        <div  ng-controller='browsePageController as browseCtrl'>
             <div ng-switch-when="browsePage">
                 <browse-page></browse-page>
             </div>
        </div> 
        <div ng-controller='otherController as otherCtrl'>
             <div ng-switch-when="homePage">
                 <other-page></other-page>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Second method:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">

   <div ng-switch="mainCtrl.currentState">
        <div ng-switch-when="browsePage">
            <browse-page></browse-page>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="otherPage">
            <other-page></other-page>
        </div>
   </div>

</div>

in "homePage.html":

<div ng-controller='homePageController as homeCtrl'>
    ......
</div>
```

Another sidequestion is..

Every time a page changes (say from browsePage to otherPage), the controller in the otherPage gets initialized (if using the second method). This actually messes with my data somewhat. Any design pattern suggestions that would help me out better ? thanks

Comment: I think it makes marginal difference if at all. Stop worrying about performance - it's only an issue if you are executing this hundreds to thousands times, so if you shave off 5ms it's significant.

Comment: it does make a big difference if i am initiating many controllers outside of their partial html pages.

Comment: @PenguinSource, how many is many?

Comment: Hmm I realized theres no point in keeping too many controllers outside and it wasn't a logical design decision and found a different solution. i was thinking 10+ controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got rid of the switches with views - used ui-router and stateProvider which proved to be quite useful in managing many issues of an angularjs app

Comment: Agreed, until you get overwhelmed with the complexity of the ui-router!

Comment: I'm not aware of the issues I may run in to, care to elaborate a bit on that? I'd like to dodge a bullet if I could ;)

Comment: So, I would recommend before putting this into a huge project and spending hours, get it into [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) and play around with it big time, get to know how states work, and the `views: { "shell": { templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html', controller: 'someCtrl' }, "subView@state": { templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html', controller: 'someCtrl' };`

Comment: I might write a blog post on this tonight, if I do I will post you a link!